# Creating cache with CacheLoaderFactory on client node brings exception

Tags: ignite

I have one remote server node,and from local client node I discover that server node. Now from client node I want to create cache 
 p.s. peerClassLoading Enabled for both configurations 
My code is following

```
   private final CacheConfiguration<> cacheConfiguration = SpringContextHolder.applicationContext 
                            .getBean("cacheConfiguration", CacheConfiguration.class); 

    ignite.createCache((CacheConfiguration<>)new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheConfiguration).setName(CACHE_NAME) 
                                                    .setReadThrough(true) 
                                                    .setCacheLoaderFactory(new LoaderFactory()) 
                                                    .setExpiryPolicyFactory(EternalExpiryPolicy.factoryOf()))) 



    public  class LoaderFactory
                    implements Factory<Loader> { 


            public Loader create() { 
                    return new Loader(); 
            } 

    } 




    public class Loader implements CacheLoader<x,y> { 



        public Loader(){
        } 

    .................................... 
    } 


        during  creating cache ,on remote node brings exception 

        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading): java.net.URLClassLoader@738defde       at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal(JdkMarshaller.java:108) 
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.messages.TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.message(TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.java:80) 
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.notifyDiscoveryListener(ServerImpl.java:4894)       at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:4750) 
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2121) 
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2208)07) 
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62) 
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.synisys.idm.apollo.internal.service.caching.loaders.LoaderFactory      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425):354) 
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)ader.java:358) 
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8250) 
                at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.resolveClass(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:54)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Denis Magda @magda
Hi,

You have to place the class of your loader factory in clients’ nodes classpath as well. The main reason for this is because when a transaction is started from a client node (that is quite a usual case) then the client first commits data to a storage and after that to in-memory.

Case with the storage is discussed in this blog post: http://gridgain.blogspot.ru/2014/09/two-phase-commit-for-in-memory-caches.html

—
Denis Magda